# why i can not get the same order of writing in the code with the pdf output file?

Tags: tables, floats

in my paper I used tables to display the results, these tables do not come in the pdf file as same as the writing's order in the latex code

Comment: That is because usually tables and figures are floating environments, which means that they don't necessarily appear exactly where they are in the code, instead they can move around ("float") to find an appropriate place where they give better page breaking and overall appearance.

Comment: Thi is a recurrent question.  I understand why is not expected at first, but just remember the layouts that you can get in any format with no floats elements an see the results now. For me there was no color.  I wonder why so many people see this like a problem and not a big feature. It should be that nobody care actually of the document layouts...